# get coordinates to draw a triangle inside another triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am not a Math guy. So, if this question is silly, then please forgive me.

I have a triangle which has the following coordinates: (all the measurements are in cm.)

```
A - (35, 0)
B - (70, 70)
C - (0, 70)
```

I have filled this triangle with black color.

Now, I want to draw another triangle inside it. I don't know what the co-ordinates of that triangle will be. But after drawing new triangle i will fill it with red color and it should look like there is a black border of 1 cm around it.

Can you please let me know the co-ordinates for new triangle?

**Update:**

@Floris gave me this value of 3 pairs of vertices:

$(70-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$, $(35,\sqrt{5})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$

In this case:

A - (35, 0)

B - (70, 70)

C - (0, 70)

P - $(35,\sqrt{5})$

Q - $(70-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$

R - $(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$

Which gives me output like:

[image]

But now suppose I want to have border of 10 cm:

So, I changed the value to: (please consider x = 10)

A - (35, 0)

B - (70, 70)

C - (0, 70)

P - 35,x√5

Q - 70-((x/2)(√5+x)),70-x

R - (1/2)(√5+x),70-x

But I am getting

[image]

I want the formula for inner triangle's vertices. In short I need P, Q, and R having some x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the edges are given by $\overline{AB}=\{(x+35,2x):x\in[0,35]\}$, $\overline{BC}=\{(x,70):x\in[0,70]\}$ and $\overline{AC}=\{(35-x,2x):x\in[0,35]\}$. The linepieces on centimetre from the edges are given by 
$$\hat{AB}=\{(35+x-\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5},2x+\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5}):x\in[0,35]\},$$ 
$$\hat{BC}=\{(x,69):x\in[0,70]\}$$
 and 
$$\hat{AC}=\{(35-x+\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5},2x+\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5}):x\in[0,35]\}$$
which have intersections $(70-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$, $(35,\sqrt{5})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1),69)$, which are the coordinates of the red triangle.

This process can be generalised for different borders. Note that
$$\hat{AB}=\overline{AB}-(\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5},\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5})$$
here $(\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5},\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5})$ is a unit vector which is orthogonal to $\overline{AB}$. So if we want a border of length $l$, then we can just take 
$$\hat{AB}_{l}=\overline{AB}-l\cdot(\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5},\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5})$$
This gives us
$$\hat{AB}_{l}=\{(35+x-\frac{2l}{5}\sqrt{5},2x+\frac{l}{5}\sqrt{5}):x\in[0,35]\},$$ 
$$\hat{BC}_{l}=\{(x,70-l):x\in[0,70]\}$$
 and 
$$\hat{AC}_{l}=\{(35-x+\frac{2l}{5}\sqrt{5},2x+\frac{l}{5}\sqrt{5}):x\in[0,35]\}.$$
To calculate the coordinates of the new triangle we have to find the intersections of the triangles, these are given by:
$$\hat{AB}_{l}\cap\hat{AC}_{l}=\{(35,l\sqrt{5})\}$$
as due to symmetry $35=35-x+\frac{2l}{5}\sqrt{5}\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{2l}{5}\sqrt{5}$. From which it then follows that $2x+\frac{l}{5}\sqrt{5}=l\sqrt{5}$.
For $\hat{AB}_{l}\cap\hat{BC}_{l}$ we can solve
$$70-l=2x+\frac{l}{5}\sqrt{5}\Leftrightarrow x=35-\frac{l}{2}(1+\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5})$$
which then gives $35+x-\frac{2l}{5}\sqrt{5}=70-\frac{l}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$. Hence
$$\hat{AB}_{l}\cap\hat{BC}_{l}=\{(70-\frac{l}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}),70-l)\}.$$
Finally by symmetry we find that
$$\hat{AC}_{l}\cap\hat{BC}_{l}=\{(\frac{l}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}),70-l)\}.$$

Comment: First of all thanks for giving me an accurate answer. I have checked (70−12(5‾√+1),69) , (35,5‾√) and (12(5‾√+1),69), and it works perfectly. I really don't understand the calculations that you have put in your answer. And now I need a border of 2 or 3 pixels at some places. So, can you please give me the formula for `border = x`? Sorry, if I asked for too much help.

Comment: @Vishal I've changed the bounds of $x$ to precisely give the edges of the red triangle.

Comment: Sorry, i was unable to explain you what exactly i need. You have given me the formula to get the sides of red triangle, but I need the formula for the vertices of red triangle. The vertices that you gave me last time works fine for me. But thats static for 1 cm border. I want that dynamic. So, that in some triangles I have border = 2 or border = 3 or border = 10, where I will be able to calculate the vertices of inner triangle by just replacing x with the desired border.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you need, could you explain by for example giving what you understand to be the vertices of a simple triangle? I'll try to go from there.

Comment: I have updated the question with relevent information. Please take a look at it. Thanks again for taking time for me.

Comment: I've given a formula for a border of length $l$ plus some explanation of how to calculate this yourself for different cases.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to update the answer. I will try it and let you know the results.

Comment: Thank you @Floris. I am really very bad at math, but you kept patience and explained me everything till I understood that. After staring at your answer and looking at every step by implementing it, i realized that i needed what you call `intersections`. Now it is working good. Thanks from the bottom of my heart.